# get a list from another list with minimum iteration in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

I have a list (Let A) which contains list of object and each object contains attribute say `name` and `id` and `id` values are stored in database.In a particular position I have list (Let B) of IDs now i want those objects in list 'A' which have ids in list 'B'.
by using simple iteration i can get those objects from list A.(It may cause more iteration)
I want to reduce the iteration as my both lists have more than 1000 of values in each

```
for clildB in B:
            for childA in A:
                #   MYCODE
```

Comment: Use of dictionary may help with keys as unique ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your O(n*m) (quadratic) code to O(n+m) (linear):

```
ids = set(B)
L = [obj for obj in A if obj.id in ids]
```

[`item in a_set` operation has O(1) (constant) time complexity (average case)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), where `a_set` is a set. Compare it with `item in a_list` that has O(n) time complexity, where `a_list` is a list.

Comment: hai @J.F. Sebastian thanks for your answer it looks nice .Can you explain how it works

Comment: @madan: the answer uses [big O notation](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) and the [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

```
idADic = {o['id']:o for o in A}
[idADic.get(o['id']) for o in B]
```